# QGIS 2.4: copying of points to another point layer

Tags: qgis, point, layers

in QGIS 2.4  it is not possible any more to copy points of a layer into another layer - I get the message:
" Fehler: Objektschreibfehler:
Objekterzeugungsfehler (OGR-Fehler: Attempt to write non-point (MULTIPOINT) geometry to point shapefile.) "

Is it a mistake of QGIS 2.4 ? In version 2.2 it was no problem. The two point-layers have the same structure (attributes)

My QGIS runs under ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in QGIS 2.4 (as shown at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10747), which has been fixed for the upcoming 2.6 release.